# How to get/extract an attachment file from a webservice reply (with Suds)?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, attachment, suds

I need to extract an [attachment](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments) from a soap webservice response.
I'd like to keep using the Python [Suds client](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/).

I can't find a way to extract this data in the Suds API. There should be a way to do this on HTTP level...

In my case the attachment is text data.

Comment: Generally attachments are fetched from the multipart. Soc heck for multipart data retreival.

Comment: I found https://github.com/dnet/suds/commit/4c930c764d8639c5d808609c756466c3e6070976 in the meanwhile.

Comment: Not sure where to monkeypatch the above.. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, by the way did you solve this? If you did, could you post the solution? It would be useful for others, for example me :)