# How to monkeypatch the suds.transport.Reply?

Tags: python, soap, suds, monkeypatching

I have been trying to modify the [Reply](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.transport.Reply-class.html) class of suds.transport.

I tried with the following approach:

```
import suds.transport
old_reply = suds.transport.Reply

class Reply2:
    """
    A transport reply
    @ivar code: The http code returned.
    @type code: int
    @ivar message: The message to be sent in a POST request.
    @type message: str
    @ivar headers: The http headers to be used for the request.
    @type headers: dict
    """

    def __init__(self, code, headers, message):
        """
        @param code: The http code returned.
        @type code: int
        @param headers: The http returned headers.
        @type headers: dict
        @param message: The (optional) reply message received.
        @type message: str
        """
        print 'hello, i patched the class'
        self.code = code
        self.headers = headers
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        s = []
        s.append('CODE: %s' % self.code)
        s.append('HEADERS: %s' % self.headers)
        s.append('MESSAGE:')
        s.append(self.message)
        return '\n'.join(s)

suds.transport.Reply = Reply2
```

When executing a `client` request (as you would normally with Suds), the default Reply is used instead of the patched one.

What could be a reason that this approach is failing?

**Note**: it seems that patching the `__init__` separately *does* give better results. But I need to modify more behaviour in the class.
In the end, I'm trying to override Reply to get incoming attachments, like asked [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414726/how-to-get-extract-an-attachment-file-from-a-webservice-reply-with-suds) and the solution [here](https://github.com/dnet/suds/commit/4c930c764d8639c5d808609c756466c3e6070976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `suds.transport.http` module imports `Reply` with the line:

```
from suds.transport import *
```

and does this *before* you can patch it. You need to update that reference too:

```
import suds.transport.http
suds.transport.http.Reply = Reply2
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right! BTW: `suds.transport.https` also `import *`, so I thought about patching that too. But in my opinion that statement is unnecessary, right? None of the classes is used from `suds.transport.__init__.py`.

Comment: @taper: `.https` doesn't use the `Reply` class, no; it just inherits from `.http.HttpTransport` which refers to the `Reply` it imported.